# Problem with image path in IE7

Tags: html, jquery, image, path

I have a problem trying to render images that are being inserted dynamically via jquery in IE7. I had image paths that were coded like this:

```
"./images/next.gif"
```

Then I changed it to this path:

```
"images/next.gif"
```

They are rendering in all the other browsers except for IE7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an absolute path:

```
"/images/next.gif"
```

The above would be what you would use if the images was in a directory called images that was in your root web directory.